# how to return a html5 page through curl?

Tags: html, curl, phantomjs

I tried to retrieve an html page using curl. 
After I logged in to a website, using the following command:

```
curl -o out.html -L -b cco.txt -c cco.txt -d "site=it&redirect_url=aHR0cDovL2l0LmFkdmZuLmNvbS9wLnBocD9waWQ9bW9u&login_username=NAME&login_password=PWWW&login_submit=Accedi" https://secure.advfn.com/login/secure
```

I get a web page with the code html5, but no data processed by it.

How can I get the data, like a browser snapshot?
No images (jpg, png...), but a text file.

Comment: what do you mean "data" ? Basically a webpage is just formatted text. It could be the site content is built dynamically using javascript, in which case you won't get the whole content through curl as it doesn't execute any javascript...

Comment: In fact! the site content is built and updated continuously dynamically, in the browser window, but curl returns only code.

Comment: In that case you actually don't need to request for the page self, but rather for the webservice / API / js file / whatever fetching data an displaying it through html...

Comment: There is an utility, cutycapt, that return a screenshot of a page, but I need a text file to parse, i.e. the text returned by html5 code executing.

Comment: there is (at least from what I know) no way to execute javascript with curl. Even google can't index dynamically generated content... What you want to do in this context doesn't seem possible to me as such. What could maybe be possible is launch an instance of a browser, load the page, and fetch the generated source from it, but I don't have a clue on where to start with that nor if it is even possible.

Comment: nope, not that I know. As I said, even Google can't do that, I don't know of any HTML/CSS/JS parsers other than browsers...

Comment: I tried to load the downloaded page out.html in the browser, but no data is shown, i.e. the code is not run properly.

Comment: The source page downloaded by curl and the source page directly opened by browser are similar, except some links to JavaScript code. Then, the non-execution of the curl downloaded page by the browser is due to a different session is not recognized by the server

Comment: There might be a lot of possible issues with that approach. Anyway, the point of all this is that you'll have to find another way of doing whatever you want to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question. Simply, curl is wrong.
I use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) an the simple code below:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
  server = 'https://secure.advfn.com/login/secure',
  data = 'site=it&redirect_url=aHR0cDovL2l0LmFkdmZuLmNvbS9wLnBocD9waWQ9bW9u&login_username=bl&login_password=PPPPPPP&login_submit=Accedi';


page.open(server, 'post', data, function (status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to post!');
  } else {
    console.log(page.content);
  }
  page.render('example.png');  //optional
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Then, it can run it on console:

```
bl@edesktop $ phantomjs --debug=true --ssl-protocol=any --cookies-file=cook.txt script.js > page
```

obtaining both a render page and a text file with all data needed, read to parsing.

Comment: Lol I just discovered PhantomJS (already saw the name before but I was curious to know what was behind it...) and was coming back here to point you into that direction.